# Gulp 4 TypeScript Compilation Errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, build-automation

I am using Gulp 4 and compiling Typescript down to javascript. For this i am using the gulp-typescript plugin. Although it does compile i recieve a bunch of errors while compliling:

Errors:

```
[17:43:02] Using gulpfile ~/Sites/dmfa/gulpfile.js
[17:43:02] Starting 'typescript'...
[17:43:02] Starting 'clean-typescript'...
[17:43:02] Cleaning: ./web/js/**/*.js
[17:43:02] Finished 'clean-typescript' after 21 ms
[17:43:02] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[17:43:02] Compiling TypeScript --> JavaScript
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterator'.
[17:43:03] TypeScript: 76 semantic errors
[17:43:03] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
[17:43:03] Finished '<anonymous>' after 1.75 s
[17:43:03] Finished 'typescript' after 1.77 s

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Although this still compiles real errors maybe be over looked and it would be more pleasing to me to correct the errors.

Can anyone give me some insight into why these errors happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone was wondering here is what fixed everything for me. I added the following at the top of my main.js file (bootstrap file). Found this here: [Angular 2 typescript can't find names](http://thankcoder.com/questions/iteet/angular-2-typescript-cant-find-names)

```
///<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

The file main.ts file looks like this:

```
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Just make sure the path is the correct path to your node_modules folder as my typescript is nested in my project.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are targeting ES5/ES3 and using features of the typescript that are supported only when compiled targeting ES6. To fix this you can try to either explicitly supply 'target' option in gulp-typescript to be ES6, or if you are feeding tsconfig to it - make sure you set target ES6 in there.

Comment: @Amind How does it effect my end result. Not all browsers support ES6 so will that result in errors in browsers with no support?

Comment: yes. you will need to use polyfills to fill in missing functionality. For example for promises you can use es6-promise. But I am not sure that you will be able co cover every feature this way. You can also transpile from es6 to es5 using babel and such but I do not really think it will fully cover either.